# Why Android Studio is ignoring files in git repo and how to import a project from git?

Tags: android, git, android-studio

Currently, I'm trying to work with a git server hosted at my company. When I'm initiating the git inside my Android projet root directory, there's some files automaticaly ignored, why ?

Next, when I clone my project in another computer (with a different OS and a different SDK installation path) and when I try to import the cloned project, Android Studio seems to not find a proper existing project : I see the gradle icon instead of the Android Studio icon :

**Project import screenshot**

[image: Project import screenshot]

How can I make a proper import ?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDE project files are meant to be ignored. These files usually contain local configuration files, like paths and configuration to run and build software depending on your machine/OS.

Importing a gradle project should result in a new Android Studio / IntelliJ project. About the files that are ignored, those should be the local build files that I mentioned.

Do you experience issues when you are just importing the project?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation, I understand. I've experienced issues when importing, but I've tried again and it works now... It seems to work then.